# Indexing in MongoDB - which is better way

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a question on designing index in MongoDB.

Say i have a users collection and groups collection.

```
user {
name : "" ,
age :  19
}

group {
name : ""
members : [],
posts :  [ { date : "" , author : "" , topic : "" }, { date : "" ,
author : "" , topic : "" } ......]
}
```

There can be 1000's of groups and each group can have millions of
posts. Operations I frequently perform is:

1. getting posts based on date (70%)
2. updating posts (30%)

So, essentially I need to index on date.

My question is:

Should i create a new posts collection like

```
posts {
name : "",  date : "" , author : "" , topic : ""
}
```

and create a single-value index on date in posts collection

```
( db.posts.ensureIndex({posts : 1}) )
```

**OR**

Should i include posts inside of group object and create an embedded
index like `db.groups.ensureIndex({ posts.date : 1})`

Which one is more efficient ? whats the best practice if this needs to
scale to millions of posts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Z5h, I think u mis-understood the problem.
The problem was getting posts of a particular group between a date range. 
and storing them most effectively.

and after some thinking and research, this's what i found out.

- First, there's a limit on size of document ( currently 16MB ), and as post schema/posts increase in size, this may **stop scaling** some day as number of posts increase.and u cannot add an index to search within array of sub documents, as indexes are only across collections.
- Second, If posts are stored as embedded sub documents, there would be no way to search within posts for a group in a date range. I have to get entire posts array and do processing on client side which is inefficient. There's no way to compare array objects based on a field in sub document as of now. refer [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements)
- **Hence better way is to create a separate posts collection** , and have foll data

  ```
  posts{
  group_name : objectID(<ID in groups collection>),
  date : "",
  author : "",
  topic : "" 
  }
  ```

By this way, i can as well create index on date and get all data for a group in a date range more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you index on a document (many key/value pairs as opposed to a value), you must search for that document exactly for the query to use the index. (e.g. if you know only the name,date,autor but not topic then the index won't be used). This really limits the usefulness in your case.

A better option is to create a compound index. For example:
`db.posts.ensureIndex({ posts.date : 1, posts.topic : 1, posts.author : 1});`
With that you could efficiently search for:
posts by date, or
posts by date and topic, or
posts by date, topic and author.
see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-CompoundKeysIndexes